# Frame bundle of associative vector bundle returns the origional prinicipal bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

**Background and definitions:** For a vector bundle $E$ let $F(E)$ denote its frame bundle. For a principal bundle $P$, and representation $(\rho,GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$ let $E(P,\mathbb R^n)$ denote the associated vector bundle that is $E(P,\mathbb R^n)=P\times \mathbb{R}/\sim$ where $(p,v)\sim(pg,\rho(g^{-1}v))$.

> **Problem** Show that $F(E(P,\mathbb R^n)\cong P$.

**Attempt:**
The fibers of $F(E(P,\mathbb R^n)$ consist of frames of the vector bundle $E(P,GL(n,\mathbb R))$ but the elements in $P$ are just points on the manifold $P$ so I am not sure how to reconcile these two ideas.

Update:
We want to show that $F(E(P,\mathbb R^n)_x\cong P_x$. Since $P$ is a $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ bundle $P_x\cong GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. I think that $F(E(P,\mathbb R^n)_x$ are frames of $E(P,\mathbb R^n)_x=\{[p,v]: p\in P_x \text{ and } v \in \mathbb R^n \}$. I think we need to use the $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ invariance of $[p,v]$ to show that any frame is uniquely defined by $p$, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: For starters, your notation is not consistent. You defined $E(P,V)$ to be the associated vector bundle with fibers (isomorphic to) the vector space $V$. But then you wrote $E(P,GL(n,\Bbb R))$. You also never said what the group of the principal bundle $P$ was. What if it's $O(n)$ or $SL(n)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin is this clear now?

Comment: No, the representation needs a vector space.  It's a homomorphism from your group to $GL(V)$. How else do you build a vector bundle?

Comment: Ah yes I wrote $E(P,GL(n,R))$ when I should have wrote $E(P,R^n)$, I hope this makes sense now